# Get activity that called parent activity of a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

In my fragment I have a 'dismiss' button that should behave in a different way dependent on which Activity called its parent activity (say TutorialActivity).

**In the TutorialActivity I am already determining which Activity called it. How to pass that data down to the fragment?**

My fragments reside in a PagerAdapter and I wouldn't like to need to pass this info as a 'newInstance()' parameter every time, as it seems an overkill, taking into consideration that this parameter would be the same for each fragment in my FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: "I wouldn't like to need to pass this info as a 'newInstance()' parameter every time, as it seems an overkill" - This sounds like a good solution to me. Another alternative could involve using `BroadcastReceiver`s and `LocalBroadcastManager`, but that sounds even more like overkill.

Comment: Use a singleton or static object i dont really support static but still can do as it has a lot of use

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable from Tutorial Activity by making this variable public. Suppose variable name is parent. You can access it by using instance of TutorailActivity (suppose instance of Activity used in fragment is mTutorialActivity) then it should be like mTutorialActivity.parent.
But you need to pass instance of TutorialActivity as it may be used for other purposes also like fetching strings from strings.xml and other purpose. So it would be beneficial to pass Activity instance instead of variable.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing: I implemented said "different behavior" in the TutorialActivity itself, having moved the dismiss button up from the fragment. Then a simple onClickListener and a switch statement inside of it.